# jQuery select value failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have done some research on this and everything said / suggested so far has failed to work.

I am trying to capture the input from a select tag, however nothing comes through, not even `null`.

The code:

```
  function validateForm()
  {
    var name = $('#txtName').val();
    var email = $('#txtEmail').val();
    var tel = $('#txtTel').val();
    var look = $('#lookingFor').val();
    var goals = $('#goals').val();
    alert(name + " " + email + " " + tel + " " + look + " " + goals);
    return false;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<select class="fomForm select" style="color:#777;" 
id="lookingFor" name="lookingFor">
<option value="">I'm looking for</option>
<option value="">CYCLING</option>
<option value="">RUNNING</option>
<option value="">TRIATHLONS</option>
<option value="">TRAINING CAMPS</option>
<option value="">PERFORMANCE TESTING</option>
<option value="">DIET &amp; NUTRITION</option>
<option value="">WELLNESS</option>
</select>
```

I apologise for asking this as there are quite a few resources on the internet however they don't seem to help this case. The name, email etc all display fine in the alert but the select boxes do not.

I have no errors in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have no value in your select box option...so the alert is empty

```
<option value="">I'm looking for</option>
<option value="">CYCLING</option>
```

replace the value with the value u want....

```
<option value="iamlookingfor">I'm looking for</option>
......
```

Comment: Oh! Cannot believe I missed that one! Thank you very much, I guess its always a case of double and triple checking everything!

Answer (score 3):

It is not showing because  all the values in your select options are empty.

Try putting some value:

```
 <option value="TRIATHLONS">TRIATHLONS</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){$(".fomForm").change(function(){
alert($(".fomForm option:selected").text()); })});
```

Take a demo in this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/tAxDv/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing the `value` for `option`s. They all say `option=""`

Put the value in there, and it should start working with `$('#lookingFor').val()`

If you don't have control on the html, or can't add values for whatever reasons, this should give you the `text` displayed in the `option`

```
$('#lookingFor option:selected').text()
```